# Customizing header in fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to make my chapter titles show in the document's header. I know of the `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` commands, but I wish to customize the look of the header while still showing the chapter titles.
This is what I currently have. It only produces "Chapter [number]: Chapter" on every page.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{title}
\fancyhead[CO, RE]{Chapter \thechapter: \chaptername{}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{name}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear but I guess you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext} % <================= dummy text or dummy document

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  %\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}% <============== standard
%}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ \textit{#1}}{}%
}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{title}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\leftmark} % <========================= LO instead CO
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{name}


\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

With package `blindtext` you can generate a dummy text or document to have a look on the generated header and footer.

To get for example an italic title of chapter in the header you can redefine the `\chaptermark` like

```
\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ \textit{#1}}{}
```

That means you get the text `Chapter` (content of `chaptername`), blank, chapter number (`\thecapter`), dot, blank, chapter titel in italic (`\textit{#1}`).

Please see I changed `CO` to `LO` to get the `\leftmark` printed left (L) instead centered (C)! Looks better imho.

With the given mwe you get the result:

[image: resulting double page]